# python thrift error ```TSocket read 0 bytes```

Tags: python, thrift

My python version:2.7.8 
thrift version:0.9.2 
python-thrift version:0.9.2 
OS: centOS 6.8 
My test.thrift file:

```
const string HELLO_IN_KOREAN = "an-nyoung-ha-se-yo"
const string HELLO_IN_FRENCH = "bonjour!"
const string HELLO_IN_JAPANESE = "konichiwa!"

service HelloWorld {
  void ping(),
  string sayHello(),
  string sayMsg(1:string msg)
}
```

client.py

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-

from test import HelloWorld
from test.constants import *

from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol


# Make socket
transport = TSocket.TSocket('192.168.189.156', 30303)

# Buffering is critical. Raw sockets are very slow
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)

# Wrap in a protocol
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)

# Create a client to use the protocol encoder
client = HelloWorld.Client(protocol)

# Connect!
transport.open()

client.ping()
print "ping()"

msg = client.sayHello()
print msg
msg = client.sayMsg(HELLO_IN_KOREAN)
print msg

transport.close()
```

server.py:

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-

from test.HelloWorld import Processor
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.server import TServer


class HelloWorldHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = {}

    def ping(self):
        print "ping()"

    def sayHello(self):
        print "sayHello()"
        return "say hello from 156"

    def sayMsg(self, msg):
        print "sayMsg(" + msg + ")"
        return "say " + msg + " from 156"


handler = HelloWorldHandler()
processor = Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket("192.168.189.156", 30303)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

server = TServer.TThreadPoolServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

print "Starting python server..."
server.serve()
print "done!"
```

My error:

```
ping()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 29, in <module>
    msg = client.sayHello()
  File "/home/zhihao/bfd_mf_report_warning_service/local_test/test/HelloWorld.py", line 68, in sayHello
    return self.recv_sayHello()
  File "/home/zhihao/bfd_mf_report_warning_service/local_test/test/HelloWorld.py", line 79, in recv_sayHello
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 126, in readMessageBegin
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 206, in readI32
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 159, in read
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 120, in read
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

Answer (score 13):

I guess this question is old, but I hit the same error message.
It turned out that there was a typo on the server side.  The thrift libraries were trying to log the message using Python logging, but I hadn't set up logging, so it just said, "No handlers could be found for logger "thrift.server.TServer"".

When I did some minimal logging, (add this code to the server side):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

The logging showed me my typo in a Python stack trace, I fixed it and it worked again.  The "TSocket read 0 bytes" error means the server got an exception and didn't write out a message.

Answer (score 3):

My OS environment problems.
I change port `30303` to `9999`, it run successfully.

Comment: In fact, I do find any bug in your codes. I make thrift server listen port 30303 and no any error.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the thrift service ,you need set protocol, like this:

```
./hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -c compact protocol;
```

In your code, you need set `protocol = 'compact'`, like this:

```
con = happybase.Connection(host='localhost',port=your thriftport,autoconnect=True,protocol = 'compact',timeout = xxx)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my implementation was raising an exception that the service endpoint wasn't specified to raise, I fixed it by adding a `throws ( 1: MyException exc)` to the end of my endpoint specification.